# Segmenting / bucketing data in Teradata ntile equvilent

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to bucket/segement data in Teradata.

I have managed to achieve this with BigQuery using:

```
ntile(5) OVER (order by pageLoadTime) Segment
```

Then grouping by and ordering by segment to produce something like this:

[image: data table image]

How would this be possible in Teradata as it doesn't support ntile. I've done a lot of Googling but can't find a solution. I have come across this from the official documentation but not sure

```
B * (RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY part_col ORDER BY data_col) - 1) 
/ COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY part_col) AS "QUANTILE"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/05/missing-functions-cume-dist-ntile One of the first hits when you google for *ntile teradata* :-)

Comment: I did try this! I've basically tried all of the first 3 pages :-)   Thanks for sharing anyway

Comment: Now I see, your calculation was copied from the blog. But this is not *official documentation* :-)

Comment: Just realised this is your original post haha. You mentioned 'thus the manuals show how to rewrite' and so I assumed you'd gotten it from official documentation.

Comment: Yep, it's the QUANTILE rewrite from the manuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to `NTILE()` in your expression would be:

```
CEILING(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pageLoadTime) * 5.0 / COUNT(*) OVER ()) AS "NTILE"
```

`NTILE()` makes sure that the groups are as close in size as possible.  It does so by splitting ties across different buckets (if necessary).  `ROW_NUMBER()` does the same thing.

`CEILING()` implements the same arithmetic as your version, but is slightly simpler.

`RANK()` produces what I consider to be a more reasonable tiling, but the tiles are not necessarily the same size.  Ties are put in the first bucket that they match.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Worked perfectly and very informative.