# Outliers calculation in sql teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, outliers, teradata-sql-assistant, iqr

I want to calculate the outliers and the quartiles and IQR within Teradata sql. As I can see teradata does nit support ntile function.

Select Ntile()

Comment: Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310184/segmenting-bucketing-data-in-teradata-ntile-equvilent